# How would tensorflow handle back propagation when you reorganized your outputs in the middle layers

Tags: tensorflow, backpropagation

I have a neural network with a hidden layer that outputs a number A, then I used a function which uses A to generate a vector. The question is can TF deal with this properly when doing back propagation? I did try it in TF and it can outputs something but I'm still not sure if the bp works correctly.

BTW, the function I used to generate vector from a number is (`V` is the output from previous layer, `d` is a value I feed in, `G` is constant):

```py
def Generator(d, V):
    dmn = []
    for k in range(G):
        d1 = tf.exp(-(((V*d-(-1+k*0.2))\**2)/(2*0.2\**2)))
        dmn.append(d1)
    return dmn
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, tensorflow can backpropagate through almost any differentiable transformation expressed in the tensorflow graph, and you'll get a visible error when the backpropagation cannot happen.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see any error so I would assume it works. But when I tried to get the weights through compute_gradient an error pops out saying I need to feed in a tensor of a certain size.

Comment: Because you're not feeding tensors to a tf.placeholder correctly. This has nothing to do with gradients.